# React-redux get site base URL / window.location

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

Hopefully this is a very simple question:

I want to create a string containing the full URL to a page on my site, like:

https://example.com/documents/1

Ideally I'd like to generate this in a react-redux `connect()`-ed container, in `mapStateToProps()`. Where the page is a grandchild of a react-router `Route` using browserHistory (so maybe I can get it from react-router or browserHistory somehow?) If necessary I'd do it in a full-on React class.

But I can't for the life of me find out how to do this. `window` (as in `window.location`) is always `undefined` in `mapStateToProps()` (no big surprise there) and in my view components' `render()` function.

So far I have only found ways to access the current route, e.g. "/documents/1", which is only a relative path and does not contain the site base url (https://example.com/)

Comment: Do you need to create this strong on the server, or just the client?

Comment: Just on the client side.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

So firstly, remember your code runs on client and server so any access to window needs to be wrapped in a check.

```
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    var path = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/someting'; // (or whatever)
  } else {
    // work out what you want to do server-side...
  }
```

If the URL you generate shows in the DOM, and on the client you populate the store with this URL before the first render, you're going to get a checksum error. If you *really* want to avoid the error you can wait until `componentDidMount()` in your root component to get/set the url.

Comment: Thanks, reading `window.location` in componentDidMount worked. I do that from the top-level component in the app and save it in the state. Can I ask a) why you suggest doing it server-side - would that be so that server-side rendering can also work? and b) how/where you would suggest storing the url from the server side such that client code can read it?

Comment: @skypecakes now that I've thought about it, yeah there's no good reason to get it on the server, so I've removed that comment from my answer.

Comment: Exactly for what I was looking for

Answer (score 15):

After componentDidMount you can have direct access to the origin location so that you can get the root url.

I use the below code in my JSX all the time so that i dont have to worry about the root path ex: dev env this would be `localhost:3000/whatever`, staging this will be `AppStaging.heroku/whatever/.....`   and in production it would evaluate to `www.myapp.com/whatever`

```
`${window.location.origin.toString()}/whateverRoute/`
```

Answer (score 10):

You Can try!!

```
window.location.origin
```

Comment: Not working on IOS...

Answer (score -2):

you can try the `URL API`. Take a look at this link for more details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

```
const url = new URL("blob:https://mozilla.org:443/")
console.log(url.origin); 
// Logs 'https://mozilla.org'
```

Comment: the op wants to pull the url dynamically based on the environment, this answer does not relate to the original problem, nor does it solve the issue of dynamic urls based on a given environment.